# How to tell if my Intel 64-bit CPU supports AMD64/x64 long mode?

Tags: cpu, 64-bit

I have Windows XP 64-bit, and am having a some weird issues with a 64-bit build of [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org).  In the release notes on SourceForge, it it says that the 64-bit version was compiled specifically for CPUs that support AMD64/x64 long mode.  How can I determine if my CPU supports this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the VirtualDub site:

> This version is compiled specifically for CPUs that support AMD64/x64 long mode, including AMD Athlon 64, AMD Athlon X2, AMD Opteron, Intel Xeon CPUs with EM64-T, and Intel Core i7 CPUs

In essence, all modern 64-bit processors. ("Intel Xeon CPUs with EM64-T" includes Core 2 (Duo), and similar)

Comment: I don't have a Core-2 Duo, I have a quad-core.  How can I tell if it supports it?

Comment: It does :)
Note that you also have to be using the right version of windows.

Comment: How can you be so sure it does?

Comment: It's a Core-2 Quad, right? Well that's the most likely, and they are Xeon based, so support EM64-T.